# BuildRpm task with kotlin dsl

Tags: gradle, rpmbuild, nebula, rpm-maven-plugin

I am migrating my groovy syntac to kotlin dsl and struggling while building the buildRpm() task provided by nebula plugin.

Currntly I have in my builod.gradle.kts

```
plugins {

  id("nebula.ospackage") version "8.3.0"

}
apply(plugin = "nebula.rpm")
```

I am creating my task with the following:

```
val buildRpm by creating(Rpm::class) {
  println("building")
}
```

and when running  `./gradlew buildRpm` I get `Unresolved reference: Rpm`

How can I create Rpm with kotlin dsl then ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you want to set up your Gradle:

```kotlin
plugins {
  id("nebula.ospackage") version "8.3.0"
}
```

You don't need apply here as that is already done when you declare your plugin usage as above above.

And the task:

```kotlin
val buildRpm by tasks.creating(Rpm::class) {

}
```

And make sure to import the `Rpm` task at the top of the file.

Comment: Two thingns: intellIj does not offer autocompletion and second if I execute that task in the main script it runs successful but not in when it is this external file

Comment: IntelliJ does have auto-completion for Gradle Kotlin DSL. I use it all the time. Maybe you need to upgrade your IntelliJ version or check the configuration?

Comment: For the second part, what do you mean by "external file"? Can you explain that?

Comment: I want to brake the main build.gradle.kts into sub files since the files is gettting too big

Comment: To do this, you add a `build.gradle.kts` into each subproject directory.